# How to get the value of selected valueField in Combobox?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I'm trying to assign a value ext:Hidden. I want to set the selected value of the field "HiddenSmo". How to get the value of selected valueField in Combobox?

```
<DirectEvents>
    <Select OnEvent="ValueSelected" After="var ind = #{ComboBoxSmo}.getValue();
        #{HiddenSmo}.setValue(#{ComboBoxSmo}.store.getAt(ind).get('code'));" />
</DirectEvents>
```

but after selection HiddenSmo="". Please help me. thanks in advance. Full code:

```
    <ext:ComboBox 
    ID="ComboBoxSmo" 
    runat="server"
    DisplayField="name"
    ValueField="IdSmo"
    TypeAhead="false"
    TriggerAction="Query"
    QueryMode="Remote"
    ForceSelection="true"
    SelectOnFocus="true"
    Disabled="false"
    Name="IDSmo">
<Store>
        <ext:Store 
            runat="server">
            <Proxy>
                <ext:AjaxProxy 
                    Url="~/Controls/DataService.asmx/GetSMOsD" >
                    <ActionMethods 
                        Read="POST" />
                    <Reader>
                        <ext:XmlReader 
                            Root="ArrayOfSMOResponse"
                            Record="SMOResponse"
                            />
                    </Reader>
                </ext:AjaxProxy>
            </Proxy>
            <Model>
                <ext:Model 
                    runat="server"
                    IDProperty="IdSmo">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:ModelField Name="code" Type="Int" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="IdSmo" Type="Int" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="name" Type="String" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
            </Model>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <DirectEvents>
        <Select OnEvent="ValueSelected" After="var ind = #{ComboBoxSmo}.getValue();
            #{HiddenSmo}.setValue(#{ComboBoxSmo}.store.getAt(ind).get('code'));" />
    </DirectEvents>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the "wrapper language" you use, combo, as any other form fields, has setter and getter of its value:

```
var val = combo.getValue(); // to get the current combo value
combo.setValue(val); // to set value of the combo to val
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one

```
App.ComboBoxSmo.getValue()
```

instead of this `#{ComboBoxSmo}.getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would use a HiddenField to store the value of the combobox selection when the combobox selection already stores it's own value.  My guess is that you are trying to workaround what you see as strange behavior within the combobox.  So here are some quick pointers I've learned while fighting with combobox's.

1. If you use a store, you need to shape the object in "setValue([object])" just like the way the store model is shaped.
2. Use "SelectedItems.Add(...)" and "UpdateSelectedItems()".  When just using Ext.Net.ListItems and adding to the Items collection on comboboxes this may not be necessary but when you use a store this seems to be required to get the combobox to play nice with the store on directevents.

   ```
   <Model>
       <ext:Model 
           runat="server"
           IDProperty="IdSmo">
           <Fields>
               <ext:ModelField Name="code" Type="Int" />
               <ext:ModelField Name="IdSmo" Type="Int" />
               <ext:ModelField Name="name" Type="String" />
           </Fields>
       </ext:Model>
   </Model>
   ```

Server Side:

```
protected void updateComboBoxSelection(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
     if (X.IsAjaxRequest)
     {
       this.ComboBoxSmo.SelectedItems.Add(new { IdSmo=101, name="foobar", code=15 });
       this.ComboBoxDateTime.UpdateSelectedItems();
     }
}
```